# Can I play Black ops 2 without playing the first one?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I have black ops 2 and havent played the 1st one. But i dont wanna play it if i dont know the story is. Is there like a quick summary for the 1st one so i dont have to play it and understand the 2nd one?

Answer (score 5):

You can play the second game and still understand everything that is going on without playing the first Black Ops, one follows the story of [Alex Mason](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Alex_Mason), while Black Ops II follows the story of his son, [David Mason](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/David_Mason).

I personally did not have the first Black Ops, neither did I ever play the campaign mode of it.  When I played through the Black Ops 2 campaign nothing was lost on me as all that I needed to know about David's father is told to you through the cut-scenes.

As for a summary you can read one [here](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Call_of_Duty:_Black_Ops#Plot) but it may contain spoilers if you ever choose to play the game later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can play Black Ops 2 with out playing Black Ops 1... But I would recommend that you play Black Ops 1 first. You will understand it a lot better.

Answer (score -1):

If you havent played the first black ops its fine but you should because it is a good game. It is very different from the first one.